# Recursion fundamentals with 2 examples

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm missing something fundamental in understanding basic recursion.

This works...

```js
function countup(n) {
  if (n < 1) {
    return [];
  } else {
    const countArray = countup(n - 1);
    countArray.push(n);
    return countArray;
  }
}

console.log(countup(5)); // Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This, on the other hand, does not. When I add more logging, can confirm that the recursion itself is working. The array push/unshift is not.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum <= startNum) {
    return [endNum];
  } else {
    const rangeArray = rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1, endNum);
    rangeArray.unshift[startNum];
    return rangeArray;
  }
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(3,5)); // Expecting [3, 4, 5]. Instead getting [5].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the `unshift` method. You need to use `()` to call a function/method. But you are using `[]`.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum <= startNum) {
    return [endNum];
  } else {
    const rangeArray = rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1, endNum);
    rangeArray.unshift(startNum);
    return rangeArray;
  }
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(3,5));
```

Comment: Oh man -- such a newbie mistake. thanks! Will accept once timer is ready.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects -

```js
function rangeOfNumbers (startNum, endNum) {
  if (startNum > endNum)
    return []
  else
    return [startNum].concat(rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum))
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(0, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(3, 7)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(rangeOfNumbers(9, 3)))
```

```js
[0,1,2,3]
[3,4,5,6,7]
[]
```

Using functional style means you can substitute a function call for it's `return` value and *always* get the correct result. This gives you the ability to reason about your programs as though they are formulas or [equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra). It is simply not possible if you use recursion with imperative style -

```js
rangeOfNumbers(3,6)
== [3].concat(rangeOfNumbers(4,6))
== [3].concat([4].concat(rangeOfNumbers(5,6)))
== [3].concat([4].concat([5].concat(rangeOfNumbers(6,6))))
== [3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6].concat(rangeOfNumbers(7,6)))))
== [3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6].concat([]))))
== [3].concat([4].concat([5].concat([6])))
== [3].concat([4].concat([5,6]))
== [3].concat([4,5,6])
== [3,4,5,6]
```

You can write the same thing as a pure functional expression -

```js
const range = (start, end) =>
  start > end
    ? []
    : [start, ...range(start + 1, end)]

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(0, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(3, 7)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(9, 3)))
```

```js
[0,1,2,3]
[3,4,5,6,7]
[]
```

This one can be visualized as -

```js
range(3,6)
== [3, ...range(4, 6)]
== [3, ...[4, ...range(5, 6)]]
== [3, ...[4, ...[5, ...range(6, 6)]]]
== [3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6, ...range(7, 6)]]]]
== [3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6, ...[]]]]]
== [3, ...[4, ...[5, ...[6]]]]
== [3, ...[4, ...[5, 6]]]
== [3, ...[4, 5, 6]]
== [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

With just one more condition we can support inverse ranges too -

```js
const range = (start, end) =>
  start > end
    ? range(end, start).reverse()
    : start == end
      ? [start]
      : [start, ...range(start + 1, end)]

console.log(JSON.stringify(range(0, 3)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(3, 7)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(range(9, 3)))
```

```js
[0,1,2,3]
[3,4,5,6,7]
[9,8,7,6,5,4,3]  // <- inverse
```

This last one can be visualized as -

```js
range(9,6)
== range(6,9).reverse()
== [6, ...range(7,9)].reverse()
== [6, ...[7, ...range(8,9)]].reverse()
== [6, ...[7, ...[8, ...range(9,9)]]].reverse()
== [6, ...[7, ...[8, ...[9]]]].reverse()
== [6, ...[7, ...[8, 9]]].reverse()
== [6, ...[7, 8, 9]].reverse()
== [6, 7, 8, 9].reverse()
== [9, 8, 7, 6]
```