# A range of numbers in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

So I wanted to make a recursive function that pushes a range of numbers inside of an array.
So I did the following:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  let arr = [];
  
  if (startNum != endNum) {
    rangeOfNumbers(startNum++, endNum);
    arr.push(startNum);
  } else {
    arr.push(endNum);
  }
  
  return arr;
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

so the way I think that should work is that in each iteration startNum should be +1 and should be pushed inside of the array and when startNum gets to endNum's value in this case 5 we should push endNum and end the recursion, why is my logic faulty, cuz what happens now is that my function exceeds the maximum call stack.

Another thing I tried was:

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  let arr = [];
  
  if (startNum == endNum) {
    return arr.push(endNum);
  } else {
    rangeOfNumbers(startNum++, endNum);
    arr.push(startNum);
  }
  
  return arr;
};
```

still exceeds the callstack, why does that happen? :(

Comment: Be aware that `startNum++` returns the original number, if you want the incremented number you need to use `++startNum` or just do `startNum + 1`

Comment: how does startNum++ return the original number tho? Shouldn't it increment it?

Comment: It does increment the value but returns the original. You can learn more [over at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment). The description tells you the difference a bit better then i did.

Comment: Oh my, how am I learning about this now :D That was a very valuable answer thank you very much!!!

Comment: Why do you use recursion for this? Why not a simple loop? Is this like an exercise at writing recursive functions?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66406282/5648954) might help with giving you an idea on how to approach it

Comment: Yeah, it is actually in fcc and I was struggling for some time to nail it and wanted to understand why my logic is incorrect.

Comment: @CaptainAnunnaki see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67653523/633183) with additional examples and explanation

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, learned a lot will dig deeper on the matter for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning the array from the first iteration.

You need to make the array one of your arguments on your recursive function so all the pushes are into the same array

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum, arr =[]) {
    if(startNum < endNum) {
        arr.push(startNum);
        rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum, arr);
    }else{
      arr.push(endNum);
    }
    return arr;
};
```

Edit:
You probably also want to call the recursion after the push so they are all in order.

And I also changed the comparison operator to a < to prevent stack overload if the function is used wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining your `arr` variable on every call, and never using the arrays returned from deeper calls. You can either pass a single array reference as Basto does in their answer, or you can run through the recursion and only define the array on the terminal call and then `unshift()` each `startNum` into the returned array.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  const arr = startNum < endNum ? rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum) : [];
  
  arr.unshift(startNum);

  return arr
};

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

`unshift()` is quite slow though. You can alter the logic to use `push()` by decrementing 'endNum' instead of incrementing 'startNum', and pushing 'endNum' on each call.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  const arr = startNum < endNum ? rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1) : [];

  arr.push(endNum);

  return arr
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5))
```

Or using [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum <= endNum
    ? [startNum, ...rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum)]
    : [];
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

Comment: Or of course, as a one-liner: `const rng = (s, e) => s <= e ? [s, ... rng (s + 1, e)] : []`

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the array in parameters :

```js
let arr = [];

function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum, arr) {
  if (startNum !== endNum) {
    arr.push(startNum);
    rangeOfNumbers(startNum + 1, endNum, arr);
  } else {
    arr.push(endNum);
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5, arr));
```

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)